# ODP.NET unmanaged driver for VS 2015

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net

there is a need to have ODP.NET unmanaged driver as Data Provider for UDT code generation (generate custom class).

Have installed ODTforVS2015_121025.exe, which provides only managed driver. How to get get/restore unmanaged driver option when defining data connection?

think, solutions for VS2012 would be relevant too if VS2015 wouldn't have one

Comment: The "MSI" installer download you found indeed only includes the managed driver (to keep the size down). There are Oracle Installer packages that include more stuff including Unmanaged. This is probably what you need: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: If you are targeting 64-bit executable, then you can use this instead: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: Finally, if you want to embed the unmanaged driver in your own installer, then look at the "XCOPY" package: 32 bit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html and 64 bit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: We are in the process of rearranging the download pages to make things a bit more sane so it is possible the above links will eventually break at some point in the future. This page will always be the top level download page though: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: thanks, Christian. It's a more complicated - Oracle 11, client is also for Oracle 11. Oracle 12 client is not an option - always gived troubles (for years). And using VS2015, don't have VS2012.
ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit shows, that Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 11.2.0.3.20 is already installed, however can't access driver in VS2015.

Comment: Are you saying that you think that you must use ODAC version 11 with Oracle 11 database? If so, that's not true, ODAC 12 is backward compatible to 11.2.0.4 databases.

Comment: @Cristian, yes, that is and should be, however unfortunately always have had problems with legacy projects when tried to move to 12 :-/
Corrent if I'm wrong - there is no way to access ODAC 11 unmanaged driver in VS2015. Only ODAC 12 should work for VS2015

Comment: If you want to use Table Adapter designers and wizards or Entity Designer with VS 2015 then you'll need Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12.1.0.2.4 or later which generates code that requires ODP.NET 12.1 or later (which is backward compatible to Oracle Database 11.2.0.4). Otherwise, if you only want to access (write code for) Oracle.DataAccess.dll (ODP.NET Unmanaged) version 11 from Visual Studio 2015 there is no problem. See the links above for options for downloading ODP.NET v 11 which you can then add to your VS2015 project.